# PreparedStatement can be use to replace a CreateStatement?

Tags: java

I am wondering if I have the following code in a Java web app:

```
Statement st = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
try {
    st = connection.createStatement();
    rs = st.executeQuery(query);
```

And I need to transform this by using a PreparedStatement can I rewritte the code as following:

```
    PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
    System.out.println("Querying..."+ query);
    
    ps.setString(1, query);
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
                    rs = ps.executeQuery(query);
```

When replacing this code my app wont give me any visible errors however when debug it wont run giving mentioning that could to generate a *createstatement*. What could be the error? Why it doesn't work?

Comment: Please show the error message and an [mcve]

Comment: If you use a `PreparedStatement` then you should execute it with `ps.executeQuery()` - i.e. without passing it the query again.

Comment: ...and if you had used a plain `Statement` then you _would_ pass the query when executing, but not when initializing the statement.

Comment: `ps.setString(1, query)` -> certainly you do not want to set the query into the first placeholder of the same query

Comment: Thank you all for your comments I think I had figured it our!